# Reinstalled VLC from scratch on Ubuntu is always looking for plugins in the wrong directory

Tags: vlc, plugins

I had vlc 2.1.5 on Ubuntu 14.04 installed by "apt-get install vlc" in /usr/bin/vlc,
it worked fine

Then I compiled and installed another version of vlc (don't remember exact version number) from source files into "/usr/local/bin/".

Then I wanted to come back to original vlc 2.1.5 and delete compiled vlc. 
For this I found all files/folders of second vlc instance by

```
sudo find /usr/local -iname vlc
```

and manually removed them by "sudo rm -rf ..."
(i didn't run "make uninstall" because I accidentally deleted source files after installation)

After this I deleted first instance of vlc:

```
sudo apt-get purge vlc
sudo apt-get autoremove vlc
```

and deleted config files

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.config/vlc
```

At this point I thought I removed both vlc instances completely (maybe I was mistaken).
Then I installed vlc from scratch again:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

And now when I run "vlc -vv" I'm getting:

```
VLC media player 2.1.5 Rincewind (revision 2.1.4-49-gdab6cb5)
[0x8ad9928] main libvlc debug: VLC media player - 2.1.5 Rincewind
[0x8ad9928] main libvlc debug: Copyright © 1996-2014 the VideoLAN team
[0x8ad9928] main libvlc debug: revision 2.1.4-49-gdab6cb5
[0x8ad9928] main libvlc debug: configured with ./configure 
[0x8ad9928] main libvlc debug: searching plug-in modules
[0x8ad9928] main libvlc debug: loading plugins cache file /usr/local/lib/vlc/plugins/plugins.dat
[0x8ad9928] main libvlc warning: cannot read /usr/local/lib/vlc/plugins/plugins.dat (No such file or directory)
[0x8ad9928] main libvlc debug: recursively browsing `/usr/local/lib/vlc/plugins'
[0x8ad9928] main libvlc debug: saving plugins cache /usr/local/lib/vlc/plugins/plugins.dat
[0x8ad9928] main libvlc debug: plug-ins loaded: 1 modules
[0x8ad9928] main libvlc debug: opening config file (/home/booch/.config/vlc/vlcrc)
[0x8ad9928] main libvlc debug: translation test: code is "ru"
[0x8ad9928] main libvlc error: No plugins found! Check your VLC installation.
```

I don't know why but new vlc installation looks for plugins in the "/usr/local/lib/vlc/plugins" folder instead of "/usr/lib/vlc/plugins"

If I run

```
export VLC_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/vlc/plugins
```

Then I'm getting this errors:

```
    booch@NAS:/usr/local$ vlc -vvv
    VLC media player 2.1.5 Rincewind (revision 2.1.4-49-gdab6cb5)
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc debug: VLC media player - 2.1.5 Rincewind
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc debug: Copyright © 1996-2014 the VideoLAN team
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc debug: revision 2.1.4-49-gdab6cb5
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc debug: configured with ./configure 
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc debug: searching plug-in modules
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc debug: loading plugins cache file /usr/local/lib/vlc/plugins/plugins.dat
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc warning: cannot read /usr/local/lib/vlc/plugins/plugins.dat (No such file or directory)
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc debug: recursively browsing `/usr/local/lib/vlc/plugins'
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc debug: saving plugins cache /usr/local/lib/vlc/plugins/plugins.dat
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc debug: loading plugins cache file /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/plugins.dat
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc warning: This doesn't look like a valid plugins cache
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc debug: recursively browsing `/usr/lib/vlc/plugins'
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc warning: cannot find plug-in entry point in /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/text_renderer/libfreetype_plugin.so
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc warning: cannot find plug-in entry point in /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/text_renderer/libtdummy_plugin.so
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc warning: cannot find plug-in entry point in /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/audio_output/libalsa_plugin.so
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc warning: cannot find plug-in entry point in /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/audio_output/libadummy_plugin.so
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc warning: cannot find plug-in entry point in /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/audio_output/libpulse_plugin.so
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc warning: cannot find plug-in entry point in /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/audio_output/libamem_plugin.so
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc warning: cannot find plug-in entry point in /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/audio_output/libafile_plugin.so
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc warning: cannot find plug-in entry point in /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/mux/libmux_ps_plugin.so
   ...
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc warning: cannot find plug-in entry point in /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_chroma/libi422_i420_plugin.so
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc warning: cannot find plug-in entry point in /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_chroma/libswscale_plugin.so
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc warning: cannot find plug-in entry point in /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_chroma/libi422_yuy2_sse2_plugin.so
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc warning: cannot find plug-in entry point in /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_chroma/libi422_yuy2_plugin.so
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc warning: cannot find plug-in entry point in /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_chroma/libyuy2_i420_plugin.so
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc warning: cannot find plug-in entry point in /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_chroma/libi420_rgb_sse2_plugin.so
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc debug: saving plugins cache /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/plugins.dat
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc debug: plug-ins loaded: 1 modules
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc debug: opening config file (/home/booch/.config/vlc/vlcrc)
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc debug: translation test: code is "ru"
    [0x9fbf928] main libvlc error: No plugins found! Check your VLC installation.
```

Could somebody please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You probably didn't remove all of vlc based on that find command. Just go to /usr/local/* and remove everything related to vlc/libvlc/libvlccore in /usr/local/bin, /usr/local/lib, /usr/local/include, /usr/local/share. Notice that in your vlc -vv output it says "configured with ./configure". The repo version would be Much more expansive

Comment: no, I removed everything related to vlc from /usr/local/* folder
here is my find output now:  

`sudo find /usr/ -iname vlc  
/usr/lib/vlc  
/usr/lib/mime/packages/vlc  
/usr/share/doc/vlc  
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/vlc  
/usr/share/menu/vlc  
/usr/share/bug/vlc  
/usr/share/vlc  
/usr/bin/vlc  `
as you can see there are no vlc in the /usr/local/* anymore

Comment: Well I'd take your word for it except your command is deficient. Did you actually browse & look?

Comment: i already solved my problem. looks like there were files with not "vlc" names from broken installation. thats why i didn't find them by "find" command. thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded source files again and run "make uninstall" and it solved my problem. Now after reinstalling vlc it runs without errors